# Handler Null Value in Looping Function ( Foreach) Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, loops, foreach

I am trying to get all value in first row `years` table (field: `colom_year`) and put in field `year_start` at `researches` table. So I use this :

```
use App/Research;
use App/Year;

public function updateDatabaseYearStartResearch()
{
    $researchs = Research::all();
    foreach($researchs as $r)
    {
            $yearNew = Year::where('research_id', $r->id) != null ? Year::where('research_id', $r->id)->first()->colom_year : 0;
            //dd($yearNew);
            $Riset = Research::find($r->id);
            $Riset->year_start =  $yearNew ;
            $Riset->save();
    }
}
```

When I `dd($yearNew)` I get value so I think I use true query. But When I comment `dd($yearNew)` to run my function I get error like this:

> Trying to get property 'colom_year' of non-object

I think that is error because there are `null` value in `years` table so I use this query to handle error:
          `$yearNew = Year::where('research_id', $r->id) != null ? Year::where('research_id', $r->id)->first()->colom_year : 0;`

But I get same error. How to fix that error?

Comment: try `(Year::where('research_id', $r->id)->first())->colom_year`

Comment: sorry @Ekown that is not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php 

$year = Year::where('research_id', $r->id)->first();

$yearNew = $year ? $year->colom_year ?? 0 : 0;
```

- Above will check if $year contains a value, if its null then assign 0
- If `$year` is a valid instance of Year having data but if does not contain column `colom_year` then again assign 0

Answer (score 0):

`Year::where('research_id', $r->id)` is an instance of a [Builder](https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html), not the result of the query itself so it won't be null. What you want to do is:

```
$years = Year::where('research_id', $r->id)->get();
$yearNew = $years->isEmpty() ? 0 : $years->first()->colom_year;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead, you should use `instanceof` to check whether `Year` is a valid object :

```
use App/Research;
use App/Year;

public function updateDatabaseYearStartResearch()
{
    $researchs = Research::all();
    foreach ($researchs as $r)
    {
        $yearNew = 0;
        $yearModel = Year::where('research_id', $r->id)->first();
        if($yearModel instanceof Year && isset($yearModel->colom_year)){
            $yearNew = $yearModel->colom_year;
        }
        //dd($yearNew);
        $Riset = Research::find($r->id);
        $Riset->year_start = $yearNew;
        $Riset->save();
    }
}
```